# Excluding Zeros from DataFrame

Tags: python, dataframe

I am trying to get rid of values that are 0.000000 in my data frame so i can find the min/max values, excluding zero.

My dataframe, Answer 2 looks like this:
[image]

and when i try to exclude zeros using the code below, I am still getting the same dataframe with the zeros intact:

```
no_zero=Answer2.loc[(Answer2!=0.000000).any(1)]
no_zero
```

Any idea on how I can remove zeros?

Comment: A chunk of dataframe might be useful

Comment: Check my answer! If it helps you, feel free to upvote it! (=

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could replace the zeros with Nan:

```
import numpy

df = df.replace(0, numpy.nan)
```

then define your own min and max functions that ignore Nan values:

```
def non_zero_min(series):
    return series.dropna().min()

df.apply(non_zero_min, axis=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

For example, where df is:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"A": [0, 2, 5, 5, 7], "B":[1, 5, 0, 1, 7]})

    A   B
0   0   1
1   2   5
2   5   0
3   5   1 
4   7   7
```

You can do this to change to np.NaN where there is a 0 for every value in the dataframe.

```
df[df != 0]
```

Then you can find the minimum or maximum value by using: `pandas.Series.min()` and `pandas.Series.max()`

For example:

```
df = df[df != 0]
df.A.min() # 2
df.B.min() # 1
```